# Best practices for using a REPL debugger with Express.js / Node.js

Tags: javascript, ruby, debugging, github, probot

I'm trying to understand how a framework built with Express.js, called [Probot](https://github.com/probot/probot), works.

I'm fairly new to JS and Node.js, but I know my way around Ruby / Rails. When I'm trying to debug something with Ruby / Rails, I'll use `[byebug][2]`. I'll insert `byebug` into my Ruby code with a running local server (i.e. `rails server`), the server process stops, and I'm able to interactively decipher my code's context near that `byebug` statement.

Is there an existing library or function that enables this same functionality with Node.js / Express.js / Probot? My scaffolded app is invoked with `npm start`, so it's not necessarily a matter of debugging regular JavaScript code, but being able to understand how my local server is interacting with an external API.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [inspector](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) in a chrome-based browser or your IDE, along with a `debugger;` [statement](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) to cause it to break at a specific location.  It's not as elegant as some other languages, unfortunately, but it does tap pretty cleanly into various tools.